# Code for (a,b) with gcd(a,b)=1?

Tags: number-theory, code-request

I am trying to make a big table that includes all ordered pairs (a,b) with a

(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,3)
(1,4)
(3,4)
(1,5)
(2,5)
(3,5)
(4,5)
(1,6)
(5,6)
...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There are infinitely many....There's `If`, `Select`, `CoprimeQ`, `Range`, `Table` to get you started

Comment: @MichaelE2: Sorry, I meant the first 500 or so, not all. :p Can you help me with the commands? I'm completely new to mathematica. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user45220 See my answer below. I have changed it now to create the first 500 pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution here. First of all create a list of all possible ordered pairs, in a range of choice (I have chosen a range of 1 to 500):

```
pairData = Subsets[Range[500], {2}]
```

Then I apply Select to the resultant dataset, where the criteria for whether or not the pairs are Coprime is given by CoprimeQ:

```
pairDataCoprime = Select[pairData, CoprimeQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &]
```

Now sorting it by the second value in each sublist, followed by the first:

```
SortBy[pairDataCorime, {Last, First}]
```

Hope that helps!

Best,

Ben

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for this. I just tried it but the output came out in an order that I don't want: First all the (1,x), then all the (2,x), etc. I want to switch this around to order it as follows: (1,x), (2,x), (3,x), etc. Then (1,x+1), (2,x+1), (3,x+1), etc. Can you help me do this?

Comment: @user45220 I have now updated the answer above to allow you to order the answer as you desired. Hope that helps! Best, Ben

Comment: This is what I had in mind, but note that `Pick[#, CoprimeQ @@@ #] &@Subsets[Range[500], {2}]` will be faster than `Select`.

Answer (score 6):

A good opportunity for the lowly procedural loop.

```
Reap[Clear[h]; n = 10; 
  Do[If[TrueQ[h[i/j]], , h[i/j] = True; Sow[{i, j}]],
 {j, 2, n}, {i, j - 1}]][[2, 1]]

(* {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 
  5}, {1, 6}, {5, 6}, {1, 7}, {2, 7}, {3, 7}, {4, 7}, {5, 7}, {6, 
  7}, {1, 8}, {3, 8}, {5, 8}, {7, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 9}, {4, 9}, {5, 
  9}, {7, 9}, {8, 9}, {1, 10}, {3, 10}, {7, 10}, {9, 10}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to find numbers `k` relatively prime to a given number `n` is to systematically check for `GCD[k,n]=1` for all `k` from 1 to `n-1`.

```
Select[Range[n - 1], GCD[#, n] == 1 &]
```

`CoprimeQ` is about as fast as `GCD`. Using `Pick` and the listability of `GCD` improves the speed.

```
RelativePrimesGCD[n_] := With[{r = Range[n - 1]}, Pick[r, GCD[r, r[[-1]] + 1], 1]]
```

A 1999 MathGroup posting discussed faster ways. Allan Hayes contributed an algorithm below, `RelativePrimesHayes[n]`, which is 15 times faster than the `RelativePrimesGCD` method above. Ranko Bojanic made some comments about, and improvements to, the code from Allan Hayes.

```
RelativePrimesHayes[n_] :=
    Fold[Complement[#, #2] &, Range[n - 1], (Range[#, n - 1, #]) & /@ 
        First[Transpose[FactorInteger[n]]]]
```

They both used `First[Transpose[FactorInteger[n]]]` to find the prime divisors of `n`, but `FactorInteger[n][[All,1]]` is faster and cleaner. Alternatively, when memory limits are not a concern,

```
RelativePrimes[n_Integer] := 
   Complement[Range[n - 1], Apply[Sequence, Map[Range[#, n - 1, #] &, 
       FactorInteger[n][[All, 1]]]]]
```

Pairs of relative primes with maximum of `n` are generated as follows.

```
Flatten[Table[Thread[List[RelativePrimes[n], n]], {n, 1, 500}], 1]
```

Comment: I don't understand the lack of upvotes - this is clearly the superior method of those posted as far as efficiency - +1

Comment: Thanks, @rasher, it is genuinely heartening to see your comment. I've learned a lot from answers by people like you here on Mma SE. Project Euler is
notoriously unforgiving of casual coding, and this gem from Allan Hayes helped a great deal with generating primitive Pythagorean triples.